# Wrong logical condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

It happens to me that I make the same mistake in logical conditions. When I want something to happened for the conditions `something is not` or `other something is not` I write this which is wrong:

```
if(el.type !== 'hidden' || !el.disabled) {
    el.value = '';
}
```

It should be this way

```
if(false === (el.type === 'hidden' || el.disabled)) {
    el.value = '';
}
```

I think: I want to clear elements value when its type is not hidden or its not disabled... - writing it down in English programming language makes bad condition.

How should I think about this logical problem to write it down right?

Comment: Try building a truth-table, then use the operator that matches the table?

Comment: it looks like what you want is `if (el.type!=='hidden' && !el.disabled) {` which also matches the natural sequential way to think about it.

Comment: Think about it – you want the if statement to be true when element type is not hidden AND element is not disabled.

Comment: OMG! Why I was down voted?

Comment: @Marecky Because that's not really a programming question and your logic is wrong. From the "correct" condition it's not clear exactly what you want either, because you seem to want AND instead of OR.

Comment: @Juhana no, I want if statement to be true if element is not hidden OR element is not disabled. Both conditions must not be at the same time

Comment: @Marecky That's what your first statement checks, but that's not what your second statement checks.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek He identified that his logic was wrong in example 1, and gave a corrected example. That's part of his point. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek my question is a programming question (because I have a problem with if-statement) and your explanation is rude

Comment: @Katana314 It's not a corrected example because it does not do *"`something is not` or `other something is not`"*, that's what I'm pointing out.

Comment: @Marecky How is _“it's not clear exactly what you want”_ or _“your logic is wrong”_ rude?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek He has moved the logical "false-checking" outside of the parentheses so he doesn't need them inside of the parentheses. This is often a much simpler way of writing multiple checks rather than inserting lots of `!` operators inbetween them. It is a corrected example. If you don't understand the example, feel free to ask questions about it, but you're being a bit quick to state someone's fault.

Comment: @Xufox "your logic is wrong" is not assertive

Comment: @Katana314 What I mean from my first statement is that there first condition satisfies "`something is not` or `other something is not`", while the corrected one does not. Where they probably mean *"Both of these somethings are not"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small gap between English semantics and logic operators. When you say "If el is not hidden or disabled" there's a mental parentheses around "hidden or disabled" in the most correct interpretation, whereas JavaScript will take it as "If (el is not hidden) or (el is disabled)" if you write it the most direct way.

You should be thinking of the second version as "If NOT: (Element is hidden, or Element is disabled.)" That's not plain English, and you will always need to work out your logic a bit. To save on typing, you can simply write as:

```
if (!(el.type === 'hidden' || el.disabled))
```

There are also correct ways of writing it with an "AND", and negation in both comparisons (as comments have noted). Sometimes, I find one or the other fits the mental model more quickly and fixes my large true/false blocks.

One thing to keep in mind when considering these situations is that if you want to negate, or turn a check into its opposite (eg, you want to turn it into its own "else" condition), you will want to turn "OR" into "AND" and vice versa.

```
if (!a && !b) {
// negated:
if (a || b)
```

Comment: @Katana314 -- Good answer - but I'd suggest that there is a *huge* gap between English semantics and logic operators. Normal language is very sloppy about using 'and' and 'or' -- Find me all businesses in London and Paris, your boss will say. She doesn't understand that she doesn't mean that (unless she specifies 'both London and Paris' - but as understanding types we reinterpret that into an SQL that uses London OR Paris - on account of we're so nice and we do know the difference.